# Elastichsearch match queries doesn't work on my prod server

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a dev and prod server both contains an identical elasticsearch cluster with the same data

Match queries on the dev server works totally fine while on the prod server I get 0 hints

is there any reasons to that ?

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index (both DEV and PROD)? Also can you define what you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: In fact all match queries gives me 0 hints on the prod server but in the dev server that works fine.

Comment: I will update my question

Comment: Please add more details to the question. Add mappings and settings so that people understand whats happening there. Just dev and prod diff is not enough.